# Insert with multiple selects using WITH/AS

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a table that looks like this: 
user(id, username, email, password)

I'd like to insert into a "relationship" table:
(id, userid1, userid2)

But this isn't working:

```
INSERT INTO relationship
WITH id1 AS (SELECT id FROM user WHERE USERNAME = "a"), 
id2 AS (SELECT id FROM user WHERE USERNAME = "b") 
SELECT id1.id, id2.id from id1, id2
```

I'm sure there's another way to do this but this seems clean and I can't figure out why it isn't working. The error I get is:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id1 AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that relationship.id is an autonumber column, try:

```
insert into relationship (userid1, userid2)
select id1, id2
from (
    (select id as id1 from user where username='a') as a,
    (select id as id2 from user where username='b') as b
    );
```

Comment: Still receiving the same error:
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id as id2 from user where username='b') as x' at line 3

Comment: Thank you so much.